# Does Visual Studio clean reinstall need ALL updates or only latest?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

If I reinstall Visual Studio 2013 on a clean box, do I need to suffer through every 4 (until now) updates as well, or is it enough to install the latest one (Update 4 currently)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to install Update 4. The updates are cumulative.

From [Update 4](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-update4-rtm-vs.aspx) page:

> This update is the latest in a **cumulative** series of feature additions
>   and bug fixes for Visual Studio 2013.

Better still, you can download the slipstreamed package (VS 2013 with Update 4):
http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/